# Attempting to use the push function to get values of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, push

I am attempting to get the value from the check boxes in my example.

I am not getting any errors, so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var interest = $('.interest');
var checkVal = [];

interest.click(function() {
  $('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked', !$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked'));
  var check = $('.interestCheck', this).val();
});
interest.change(function() {
  $('.interestCheck:checked').each(function() {
    checkVal.push($(this).val());
  });
});

var checkSelected;
checkSelected = checkVal.join(',');
console.log(checkSelected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="interest">
  <h3 class="interestTitle">A</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="A" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <h3 class="interestTitle">B</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="B" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <h3 class="interestTitle">C</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="C" class="interestCheck">
</div>
```

```
var interest = $('.interest');
var check = [];
interest.click(function() {
  $('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked', !$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked'));
  check = $('.interestCheck', this).val();
});
interest.change(function() {
  $('.interestCheck:checked').each(function() {
    check.push($(this).val());
  });
  var checkSelected;
  checkSelected = check.join(',');
  console.log(checkSelected);
});
```

Update: Full-Code

```
var interest = $('.interest');
    //var checkVal = [];
    interest.click(function() {
        $('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked', !$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked'));
        var check = $('.interestCheck', this).val();
        $('.interestBox', this).toggleClass('active');
    });
    var interestIn = $('.interest input');
    interestIn.change(function() {
        var checkVal = [];
        //$('.interestCheck:checked').each(function() {
        $('.interestCheck').is(':checked').each(function() {
            checkVal.push($(this).val());
            //var checkSelected;
        //checkSelected = checkVal.join(',');
        //console.log(checkSelected);
        console.log(checkVal.join(","));
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="interest">
                        <div class="interestBox">
                            <img src="https://image.com" alt="Aluminum Profile Framing">
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="interestTitle">Aluminum Profile</h3>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Aluminum Profile" class="interestCheck">
                    </div>
```

Comment: Do you expect the console.log to run every time you update? You only log the values at the start and there is nothing in the array...

Comment: @epascarello I just made an edit in my last attempt to try to include 'check' into the array. No luck though.

Comment: `var checkSelected;
    checkSelected = check.join(',');
    console.log(checkSelected);`  HAS to be inside/run after you change the array. It is not going to magically update.

Comment: @epascarello Ahh. I see thank you. I changed that, but still not logging the values. I changed my edit on here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... You attempt to use the checkboxes only to carry a value if "selected".

I suggest you to use a data attribute instead... And get rid of the checkboxes.
You can read those data attributes using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
var interest = $('.interest');

interest.click(function() {

  //The array to gather all data attribute values.
  var checkVal = [];
  
  // Toggle the active class.
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  
  // Gather the values.
  interest.each(function(){
    if($(this).is(".active")){
      checkVal.push($(this).data("title"));
    }
  });
  console.log(checkVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="interest" data-title="A">
  <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="A">
  <h3 class="interestTitle">A</h3>
</div>
<div class="interest" data-title="B">
  <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="B">
  <h3 class="interestTitle">B</h3>
</div>
<div class="interest" data-title="C">
  <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="C">
  <h3 class="interestTitle">C</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I have been playing with this for a while and I cannot get it to work the same as yours. I can't get anything to display in console.log. It is like the change function isn't working. I added my full JS code. Do you see anything that would be preventing it from working?

Comment: `$('.interestCheck').is(':checked')` returne a boolean `true/false`... So the `.each()` can't run. You may try `$('.interestCheck:checked')` instead... And look for the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: I had `$('.interestCheck:checked')` up until my last try. I added the `is` function to see if it would work. Is there anything else standing out to you?

Comment: Does it matter that I am not clicking on the actual checkbox? I have the checkbox set as `display: none` and am clicking on an image instead. This is what is in the `click` function in my full code above. I added the actual HTML.

Comment: Okay... You have a `click` handler on the wrapping `div`.. So when you click directly on the checkbox, that `click` event bubbles up to the wrapping div... So both script runs. To prevent that, use `.stopPropagation`, like in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/NYzbOL?editors=1011)

Comment: I don't actually click the checkbox. The checkbox is not displayed.

Comment: I recreated this in a jsfiddle - don't have a codepen account. I hid the checkbox input. You can see, even with an alert, nothing happens when you click on the image (what I am actually doing in the real environment). https://jsfiddle.net/qers48xL/

Comment: Okay... Since the checkbox is not visible, it's useless. Even if you change its checked state programmatically, the change event will not fire. It only fires on user action. So I suggest you to use a `data` attribute instead. I updated your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qers48xL/12/ If you have many... You still can use an array to gather all the `.active` `.data("title")`.

Comment: I will uppdate my answer if that is doing what you really want it to do... ;)

Comment: Yes, it is now showing on the click of the image. Are you able to join data attributes as an array like the other example?

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I appreciate your willingness to help me out through the process!

Answer (score 1):

`$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked', !$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked'))` is not enough to trigger `.change()` on the checkbox so you need to add the latter to the former:

I don't know if this is all you needed, let me know

```js
var interest = $('.interest');
//var checkVal = [];
interest.click(function() {

  $('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked', !$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked')).change();
  var check = $('.interestCheck', this).val();
  $('.interestBox', this).toggleClass('active');
  
});

var interestIn = $('.interest input');

interestIn.click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
interestIn.change(function() {
  var checkVal = [];
  //$('.interestCheck:checked').each(function() {
  if($('.interestCheck:checked').length>0)
  $('.interestCheck:checked').each(function() {
    checkVal.push($(this).val());
    //var checkSelected;
    //checkSelected = checkVal.join(',');
    //console.log(checkSelected);
    console.log(checkVal.join(","));
  }); else console.log('NONE');
});
```

```css
.interest input {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="Aluminum Profile Framing">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Aluminum Profile</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Aluminum Profile" class="interestCheck">
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason this is outputting each choice over and over instead of just the choice? For instance if you expand the html (copy and paste the block 2 times). Change the values to A,B,C. You will see what I mean.

Comment: @Paul, just a question, should I copy&paste `<div class="interest">` too or is it just a container?